# How to insert row into table when update event occurs in another table?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have two tables named **del_stu** and **del_emp**.

[image]

[image]

I want to insert a row into the **del_emp** table when updating the **del_stu** table. and I wan to insert the row which updated by the **del_emp**. I have been created a trigger for that as follows.

```
create trigger before_update_stu
before update
on del_stu
for each row
begin
    insert into del_emp
    set
    del_emp.emp_id = del_stu.stu_id,
    del_epm.emp_name = del_stu.stu_name,
    del_emp.salary = stu_emp.salary;
end
```

But this shows the following error.

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'del_epm.emp_name' in 'field list'
```

So how to do this task? That means how to change my trigger in order to do this task?
If you not clear about the task,

- **The task**

I want to insert a row(updated by the del_stu table) into the **del_emp** table

Comment: Even if you figure out the [right way](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) - You can't do that. The second update on the same `del_stu` row will fail, because you will try to insert a duplicate primary key (`emp_id`) into `del_emp`. So first you have to fix the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a spelling issue for that particular column.
You should have
del_emp.emp_name.
Otherwise syntax looks fine for MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Need to use "**OLD**" keyword for that. The following code worked.

```
create trigger before_update_stu
    before update
    on del_stu
    for each row
    begin
        insert into del_emp
        set
        emp_id = OLD.stu_id,
        emp_name = OLD.stu_name,
        salary = OLD.salary;
    end
```